# Continuous Functional Calculus Argument in Fell's Paper

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am reading an old paper of Fell's and I am having some problems sorting out one of his continuous functional calculus arguments. The essential problem is this.

Let $A$ be a C$^{*}$-algebra and let $b$ and $p$ be elements in $A$ such that $b$ is positive and $p$ is a projection with the additional assumptions that:

1) $pbp=b$

2) $\|p-b\|<1/8$.

Let $\psi\colon\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ be continuous and bounded function that satisfies
$$
\begin{aligned}
\psi(r)=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if } r=0,\\
1&\text{if } |r-1|\leq 1/8.
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

> The claim is that $\psi(b)=p$.
>   I am having trouble showing this. I'm not sure how to relate fact 2) with the fact that $\psi$ is identically $1$ on $[7/8,9/8]$ and, moreover, how to use this (or another method) to yield the result.

Comment: Another way to see it: If $A_p$ denotes the unital C*-algebra $pAp$, with unit $p$, then $b$ is a positive invertible element in $A_p$. So the spectrum $\sigma_{A_p}(b)$ is contained in $[7/8,9/8]$ which shows that $\psi(b)$ is the identity of $A_p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $C^*$-subalgebra generated by $b$ and $p$ is commutative.  So, we may assume without loss of generality that our $C^*$-algebra is $C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$.  We then have a function $p\in C(X)$ which only takes the values $0$ and $1$ and a nonnegative function $b\in C(X)$ such that $bp=b$ and $|p(x)-b(x)|<1/8$ for all $x\in X$.  So, at points $x\in X$ such that $p(x)=0$, we have $b(x)=0$.  Moreover, at points $x\in X$ such that $p(x)=1$, we have $b(x)\in [7/8,9/8]$.

On an algebra of the form $C(X)$, the continuous functional calculus is just composition: $\psi(b)$ is the composition $\psi\circ b$.  By our description of $b$ above, we see that $\psi(b(x))=0$ when $p(x)=0$ and $\psi(b(x))=1$ when $p(x)=1$.  Thus, $\psi\circ b=p$.